# Apply weights in rpart model gives error

Tags: r, function, rpart

I'm using the `rpart` package to fit some models, like this:

```
fitmodel = function(formula, data, w) {

    fit = rpart(formula, data, weights = w)
}
```

#### Call the custom function

```
fit = fitmodel(y ~ x1 + x2, data, w)
```

This causes the error:

`Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'w' not found`

Then i decided to use

```
fitmodel = function(formula, data, w) {

    data$w = w
    fit = rpart(formula, data, weights = w)
}
```

This works, but there's another problem:

#### This will work

```
fit = fitmodel(y ~ x1 + x2, data, w)
```

#### This does not work

```
fit = fitmodel(y ~ ., data, w)
```

`Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'w' not found`

What's the correct way to apply weights inside a custom function? Thanks!

Comment: try `environment(formula) = sys.frame(sys.nframe())`. This is probably from the formula being defined in a different environment than the function (probably the global environment) which is where `rpart` will look for variables.

Comment: For which case? thanks!

Comment: The first case. Are you calling this function from within another function?

Comment: Yes, there's a chain of calls.

Comment: Are you writing your own implementation of adaboost?

Comment: Yes, but how did you knew that?? I'm just playing around with the algorithm, nothing serious.

Comment: I had to do that for a class in college and came across this very issue. I'm adding an answer as kind of a long comment. I don't know a whole lot about environments and R's search path so I hope someone else comes along and adds a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully someone else gives a more complete answer. The reason why `rpart` can't find `w` is that `rpart` searches the environment that the formula is defined in for data, weights, etc. The formula is created in some environment most likely the `GlobalEnv` and the `w` is created within some other function. Changing the environment of the formula to the environment where `w` is created with `parent.frame` fixes that. `rpart` can still find the data since the search path will always continue to the `GlobalEnv`. I'm not sure why the `sys.frame(sys.nframe())` works since the environments aren't the same but apparently `w` is still somewhere on the search path

edit: `sys.frame(sys.nframe())` seems to be the same as setting the environment of the forumla to the environment of the function `rpart` is called in (`foo3` in this example). In that case, `rpart` looks for `w`, `data`, etc. in `foo3`, then `bar3` then the `GlobalEnv`.

```
library(rpart)
data(iris)

bar <- function(formula, data) {
   w <- rpois(nrow(iris), 1)
   print(environment())
   foo(formula, data, w)
}

foo <- function(formula, data, w) {
  print(environment(formula))
  fit <- rpart(formula, data, weights = w)
  return(fit)
}


bar(I(Species == "versicolor") ~ ., data = iris)
## <environment: 0x1045b1a78>
## <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
## Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) (from #2) : object 'w' not found


bar2 <- function(formula, data) {
  w <- rpois(nrow(iris), 1)
  print(environment())
  foo2(formula, data, w)
}

foo2 <- function(formula, data, w) {
  print(environment(formula))
  environment(formula) <- parent.frame()
  print(environment(formula))
  fit <- rpart(formula, data, weights = w)
  return(fit)
}

bar2(I(Species == "versicolor") ~ ., data = iris)
## <environment: 0x100bf5910>
## <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
## <environment: 0x100bf5910>


bar3 <- function(formula, data) {
  w <- rpois(nrow(iris), 1)
  print(environment())
  foo3(formula, data, w)
}

foo3 <- function(formula, data, w) {
  print(environment(formula))
  environment(formula) <- environment() ## seems to be the same as sys.frame(sys.nframe())
  print(environment(formula))
  print(environment())
  fit <- rpart(formula, data, weights = w)
  return(fit)
}

bar3(I(Species == "versicolor") ~ ., data = iris)
## <environment: 0x104e11bb8>                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
## <environment: R_GlobalEnv>                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
## <environment: 0x104b4ff78>                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
## <environment: 0x104b4ff78>
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll try to understand this better!

Comment: @Fernando I figured out why the last example works and edited the answer. Hopefully the edit makes sense and explains things a bit better.

Answer (score 1):

According to the rpart documentation (March 12, 2017, page 23, section 6.1), "Weights are not yet supported, and will be ignored if present."

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpart/vignettes/longintro.pdf

Comment: Although when you add weights it does make a difference to the answer! Maybe the documentation is wrong!

Comment: Ok, I contacted the author and this comment is out of date. Weights are indeed implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve this using the code below, but i'm sure there's a better way:

#### The weak learner

```
fitmodel = function(formula, data, w) {

    # just paste the weights into the data frame
    data$w = w
    rpart(formula, data, weights = w, control = rpart.control(maxdepth = 1))
}
```

#### The algorithm

```
ada.boost = function(formula, data, wl.FUN = fitmodel, test.data = NULL, M = 100) {

    # Just rewrites the formula and get ride of any '.'
     dep.var = all.vars(formula)[1]
     vars = attr(terms(formula, data = data), "term.labels")
     formula = as.formula(paste(dep.var, "~", paste(vars, collapse = "+")))


    # ...more code
}
```

Now everything  works!

Comment: Hola @Fernando, what is the purpose of the weights argument in the rpart function? I looked at the documentation but did not find any explanation. Can weights be arbitrary real numbers or they need to be [0,1]? Thank you.

Comment: I guess they are the initial 'importance' you want to give for each observation. By default every sample gets the same weight of 1, but i'm not sure.