# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object not found

Tags: r, function, wrapper

I am experiencing some difficulties in writing a 'wrapper' function, which should take all the arguments for an existing function plus one additional argument, then perform some calculations on that additional argument, pass everything to the original function and return the output.

To the best of my understanding, the problem is that the function I am trying to 'wrap' does not search for the argument I'm trying to pass in the local environment, but in the global environment. I don't know how to solve this problem.

Below is my stab at a minimal code that reproduces the error. In this example I am not performing any calculations on the 'passtheseweights' argument, because I don't think the calculations are relevant for the question.

```
require(rpart)
df<-car.test.frame
wt<-runif(nrow(df))
wt<-wt/sum(wt)

df<-data.frame(df, wt)

#Attempt 1
wrapfun<-function(formula, data, passtheseweights, ...)
{
  print(passtheseweights)
  outputmodel<-rpart(formula=formula, data=data, weights=passtheseweights, ...)
  return(outputmodel)
}

wrapfun(Price~Country + Reliability + Mileage + Type + Weight + Disp. + HP, data=df, passtheseweights=df$wt, method="anova", minsplit=4)

#Attempt 2
wrapfun<-function(formula, data, passtheseweights, ...)
{
  print(data[,passtheseweights])
  outputmodel<-rpart(formula=formula, data=data, weights=data[,passtheseweights], ...)
  return(outputmodel)
}

wrapfun(Price~Country + Reliability + Mileage + Type + Weight + Disp. + HP, data=df, passtheseweights="wt", method="anova", minsplit=4)

#Attempt 3, this is working....
wrapfun<-function(formula, data, passtheseweights, ...)
{
  print(passtheseweights)
  outputmodel<-rpart(formula=formula, data=data, weights=passtheseweights, ...)
  return(outputmodel)
}

wt<-df$wt
wrapfun(Price~Country + Reliability + Mileage + Type + Weight + Disp. + HP, data=df, passtheseweights=wt, method="anova", minsplit=4)

#But only because the function uses wt from the global environment. The same example also works if no passtheseweights argument is passed
wrapfun<-function(formula, data, ...)
{
  print(passtheseweights)
  outputmodel<-rpart(formula=formula, data=data, weights=passtheseweights, ...)
  return(outputmodel)
}

passtheseweights<-df$wt
wrapfun(Price~Country + Reliability + Mileage + Type + Weight + Disp. + HP, data=df, method="anova", minsplit=4)
```

If anyone knows how I can force rpart to search for passtheseweights locally, your help would be tremendously appreciated!

Best,
CJ

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/a/22260104/6455166?

Comment: Thank you! I read several questions pertaining to this error message, but appeared to have a different cause. Thank you for alerting me to this question which clearly addresses the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `do.call`:

```
wrapfun<-function(formula, data, passtheseweights, ...)
{
  outputmodel <- do.call(rpart, list(formula=formula, data=data, weights=passtheseweights, ...))
  return(outputmodel)
}
wrapfun(Price~Country + Reliability + Mileage + Type + Weight + Disp. + HP, 
        data=df, passtheseweights=df$wt, method="anova", minsplit=4)
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you so much! Am I correct that this works because do.call has a default parameter "envir = parent.frame()", which causes do.call to look for all arguments in the environment of my wrapfun function?

Comment: I'm not sure. I rather believe that it works because all arguments (including the formula) are evaluated together in the same environment when the list is created.